# Android Studio 4.1 Project Settings

Tags: android-studio

In the previous version of Android Studio I could go to File -> Project Settings.

This is gone in the new version.

What I need in particular is to have the ability to create new folders instead of new packages.

[image: Folder package]

Theme and Views are folder, and Utils is package, all new are added as packages.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @XueQing I installed android studio in a different OS, and the new install does not do this any more. IDK if it is related to the new version or not, really, it just stopped happening (4.1.3)